# draw svg marker in path

Tags: javascript, svg

I would draw marker in a path but unfortunately only line is printed.

I'm defining marker in `defs` then call it by id in my path but marker is not working.

```html
<svg id="Calque_1" data-name="Calque 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
    <defs>
      <style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke-width:5px;}.cls-1,.cls-2{stroke:#a15256;}.cls-2{fill:#fff;}.cls-3{isolation:isolate;font-size:42.79px;font-family:ArialMT, Arial;}</style>
      <marker id='start' orient="auto" markerWidth='2' markerHeight='4' refX='0.1' refY='1'>
      <!-- triangle pointing right (+x) -->
      <path d='M0,0 V2 L1,1 Z' fill="orange"/>
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <title>line</title>
    <path id="path7" class="cls-1" d="M202,67.72,329.33,215.86" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" marker-mid="url(#start)" />
  
   
</svg>
```

Comment: a line with 2 points does not have any mid vertices it only has a start and an end.

Comment: so no possible to draw arrow at beginning ?

Comment: sure but that would be marker-start, not marker-mid (the other end is marker-end)

Answer (score 1):

There is no vertex in your path

> The marker is rendered on every vertex other than the first and last vertices of the path data.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/marker-mid

Your path is `d="M202,67.72,319.33,215.86"` and that's only two points. so the `marker-mid` would not show.

Not sure but I guess what you really need is `marker-end` ?

```html
<svg id="Calque_1" data-name="Calque 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
   <defs>
  <style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke-width:5px;}.cls-1,.cls-2{stroke:#a15256;}.cls-2{fill:#fff;}.cls-3{isolation:isolate;font-size:42.79px;font-family:ArialMT, Arial;}</style>
  <marker id='start' orient="auto" markerWidth='2' markerHeight='4' refX='0.1' refY='1'>
  <!-- triangle pointing right (+x) -->
  <path d='M0,0 V2 L1,1 Z' fill="orange"/>
  </marker>
</defs>
    <title>line</title>
    <path id="path7" class="cls-1" d="M202,67.72,319.33,215.86" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" marker-end="url(#start)" />
  
   
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the marker in the middle you need to add a point to the path. In this case I'm using `d="M202,67.72 L265.665, 141.79 329.33,215.86"` instead of `d="M202,67.72 L329.33,215.86"`

```html
<svg id="Calque_1" data-name="Calque 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
    <defs>
      <style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke-width:5px;}.cls-1,.cls-2{stroke:#a15256;}.cls-2{fill:#fff;}.cls-3{isolation:isolate;font-size:42.79px;font-family:ArialMT, Arial;}</style>
      <marker id='start' orient="auto" markerWidth='2' markerHeight='4' refX='0.1' refY='1'>
      <!-- triangle pointing right (+x) -->
      <path d='M0,0 V2 L1,1 Z' fill="orange"/>
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <title>line</title>
    <path id="path7" class="cls-1" d="M202,67.72 L265.665, 141.79 329.33,215.86" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" marker-mid="url(#start)" />   
</svg>
```

In order to know where to add that point you can do the following:

- first you need to know the length of your path: `path7.getTotalLength()` If you need the point in the middle of the path this should be a point at half length.
- In order to get the coords of the point you can use the `getPointatLength()` method:
  `path7.getPointAtLength(path7.getTotalLength()/2)`. This is returning an SVGPoint and you can use the values for the x and y of this point to add a point to your path.